# Spray-Json: serialize None as null

Tags: scala, akka-http, spray-json

I am porting a rest API to scala, using akka-http with spray-json.

The old API had the following response:

```
{
    "result": { ... },
    "error": null
}
```

Now I want to maintain exact backwards compatibility, so when there's no error I want an `error` key with  a `null` value.

However I can't see any support for this in spray-json. When I serialize the following with a `None` error:

```scala
case class Response(result: Result, error: Option[Error])
```

I end up with

```
{
    "result": { ... }
}
```

And it completely drops the error value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NullOption`](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#nulloptions) trait should serialise nulls

> The `NullOptions` trait supplies an alternative rendering mode for
>   optional case class members. Normally optional members that are
>   undefined (`None`) are not rendered at all. By mixing in this trait into
>   your custom `JsonProtocol` you can enforce the rendering of undefined
>   members as `null`.

for example

```
import spray.json._

case class Response(result: Int, error: Option[String])

object ResponseProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol with NullOptions {
  implicit val responseFormat = jsonFormat2(Response)
}
import ResponseProtocol._

Response(42, None).toJson
// res0: spray.json.JsValue = {"error":null,"result":42}
```